# VB.NET SQL Database Login

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, authentication

I have a database login working with use of a MySQL database. The user is brought to a menu screen if their login is successful. Everything works fine but what I'm trying to do is bring the user to a separate admin screen if their "UserGroup" field in the database says "Admin"

I'm stuck so far, the working code for everything is as follows:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmLogin
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;port=3307;userid=root;password=Djmmcm93;database=dojodb"

        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader ' had to be declared inside the button or would not work


        Try
            MysqlConn.Open() ' opening the connection to the DB
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from dojodb.userinfo where UserID='" & txtUserID.Text & "' and Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader 'executes the command and reads data from db

            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0
            While reader.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While

            If count = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome!")
                Me.Hide()
                frmUserMenu.Show()
            ElseIf count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("username and password are duplicated!") 'Only here as test
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("username and password are incorrect!")
            End If

            MysqlConn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 'printing the exact error to help future testing if needed
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please don't share your root password on the public internet.

Comment: Also, that code is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Triple whammy: it's also really really bad to store passwords in plain text. I know this is likely just a practice app, but seeing code for "practice apps" with practices like this online is why this kind of thing ends up in a production app somewhere.

Comment: Hey Joel, I know its vulerable, its just a test phase right now, I just want to get the logic of it all working for the moment, those issues will be changed quite soon, as there is no data stored onto this that anyone could use, but thanks you are right in what you have said!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify the next portion of your code:

```vb
Dim count As Integer
Dim UserGroup As String = ""   ' <───────  Insert this line.
count = 0
While reader.Read
    count = count + 1
    UserGroup = reader("UserGroup").ToString   ' <───────  Insert this line ("UserGroup" is the name of the field in the UserInfo table).
End While

If count = 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Welcome!")

    If UserGroup = "Admin" Then   ' ' <───────  Insert this If to verified UserGroup.
        ' bring the user to separate admin screen
    Else
        Me.Hide()
        frmUserMenu.Show()
    End If
ElseIf count > 1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("username and password are duplicated!") 'Only here as test
Else
    MessageBox.Show("username and password are incorrect!")
End If
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, I tried that and tried to switch around some things too and no luck!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed and changed was SELECT *. For performance reasons, you should try never to select * and specify columns you want. If there are more columns, feel free to add them.

Then I adjusted your code, hopefully it helps you:

```vb
Public Class frmLogin
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Private Sub btnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;port=3307;userid=root;password=Djmmcm93;database=dojodb"

        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader ' had to be declared inside the button or would not work


        Try
            MysqlConn.Open() ' opening the connection to the DB
            Dim query As String
            query = "select UserID,Password from dojodb.userinfo where UserID='" & txtUserID.Text & "' and Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
            Dim userStatus = "select UserGroup from dojodb.userinfo where UserID='" & txtUserID.Text & "' and Password='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
            command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader 'executes the command and reads data from db

            If UserGroup = "Admin" Then

                'Send to admin page here


            Else            

                Dim count As Integer
                count = 0
                While reader.Read
                count = count + 1
                End While

                If count = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome!")
                Me.Hide()
                frmUserMenu.Show()
                ElseIf count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("username and password are duplicated!") 'Only here as test
                Else
                MessageBox.Show("username and password are incorrect!")
                End If

                MysqlConn.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) 'printing the exact error to help future testing if needed
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for your contribution. Unfortunately that didn't work, I tried an alteration of your code too.

It would be related to fitting in the "userStatus" variable into the executed SQL statement to allow further querying with use of the If statement which you added, but I cant figure it out